# Linux User Permissions

Tags: linux, unix

In resume i want to assume a id on a Unix machine but i wanna know if its possible to limite to only read rights and no write on the system , but if you enter the acc i sudo to normally without the origin being a sudo command then you can write if you came from other user you cant !

Comment: Might be a better fit for superuser, but could do with a clearer explanation of your problem... Didn't downvote though...

Comment: the situations is a bit tricky and its only a yes or not answer that i need , i have a production machine that needs a quick review from time to time but i would not like to have a write permission and i dont want to change the permissions on my original user, so i want to know it its possible to go to the admin acc from my acc on the command line but only with read rights ... and without the write permissions that the admin have .

Comment: You want to go to the admin account, but without it being an admin account ? (without the write permissions)... That's like saying you want to be Santa, but without the beard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not switch to the admin/root user without also obtaining the write permissions that the admin/root user has.